# Numpy, increment values in a 2D array using index represented in another 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example of what I would like to do:
Assume Array A

```
A = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 5, 9], 
              [2, 7, 5, 1, 4]])
```

And Array B

```
B = np.array([2, 4])
```

I am looking for an operation that will increment the element indexed by array B in each row of array A by 1.
So the result A is:

```
A = np.array([[0, 1, 4, 5, 9], 
              [2, 7, 5, 1, 5]])
```

The index 2 of first row is increased by 1, and the index 4 of second row is increased by 1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using advanced indexing in numpy:

```
A[np.arange(len(B)), B] += 1
```

This works by creating a `2D` array with dimensions `(len(B), len(B))` using `np.arange(len(B))`, which represents the row indices. The second index of the advanced indexing, B, represents the column indices. By adding 1 to `A[np.arange(len(B)), B]`, you increment the elements in each row specified by B.

Answer (score 0):

In `numpy` you can do by using `arrange` and `shape` of an array

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 5, 9], 
              [2, 7, 5, 1, 4]])
B = np.array([2, 4])

A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), B] += 1

print(A)
```

`np.arange(A.shape[0])` generates an array of integers from `0 to A.shape[0] - 1`. `A.shape[0]` is basically **rows**

you can do with looping also..

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 1, 3, 5, 9], 
              [2, 7, 5, 1, 4]])
B = np.array([2, 4])

for i, index in enumerate(B):
    A[i][index] += 1

print(A)
```